# Beautiful Soup HTML Parser Loop for folder

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to create a loop to run BeautifulSoup over all files in a folder and saving to a different folder under the same name. Below is what I got so far (which doesn't work either), can someone help?

```
import os
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

path = "/content/raw"
destpath ="/content/final"

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        fullpath = os.path.join(path, filename)

        soup = BeautifulSoup(open(fullpath), 'lxml')
        open(filename, 'wb').write(soup)
```

Comment: Try `open(os.path.join(destpath, filename), 'wb').write(soup)`

Comment: No that doesn't help, still returns an error: ```TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'BeautifulSoup'```

Comment: should have included the error you were getting in the question

Comment: try `open(filename, 'w').write(str(soup))`

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], as well as the entire error message.